# OAuth2 with Laravel Passport and DarkaOnLine / L5-Swagger - no code_challenge

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, swagger

I want to make DarkaOnLine / L5-Swagger docs for my API with Authorization Code Grant with PKCE. As I understood I have to use authorization type accessCode like so in package config:

```
/* Open API 3.0 support */
                'passport' => [ // Unique name of security
                    'type' => 'oauth2', // The type of the security scheme. Valid values are "basic", "apiKey" or "oauth2".
                    'description' => 'Laravel passport oauth2 security.',
                    'in' => 'header',
                    'scheme' => 'https',
                    'flows' => [
                        "accessCode" => [
                            "authorizationUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/authorize',
                            "tokenUrl" => config('app.url') . '/oauth/token',
                            "refreshUrl" => config('app.url') . '/token/refresh',
                            "scopes" => []
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

On this step I have 2 problems:

1; When I click Authorize on my Swagger docs page, I get error:

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.","hint":"Check that all required parameters have been provided","message":"The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."}
```

It is because client_id in request is empty. Does anybody knows where can I config what client_id will be used?

2; If I manually put my public client_id in the request, I can go futher, but this time I get error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.","hint":"Code challenge must be provided for public clients","message":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."}
```

So, the needed for this flow code_challenge doesnt exist in the request. Please, advice me how can I add missing params or what am I doing wrong?